# ClientModel::create($validations) does not receive value in code verification snippet

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem checking if a certain snippet in my code is being passed parameters. The snippet that has the IF is never called even when I do the validations on the form so that it is possible to enter this condition.

I used `dd($validations);` and `dd($ClientModel::create($validations));` And they only return the information array when all form fields are validated, otherwise they always return to the form showing the fields to be correctly validated.

- [Using dd($validations)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd35z.png)
- [Using dd($ClientModel::create($validations))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjQSK.png)

```
    public function store(ClientRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $validations = $request->validated();
            dd($ClientModel::create($validations)); // Only work and return array datas when fields of form are correctly fillables
            if (!ClientModel::create($validations)){ // No working
                throw new Exception($this->logClient->logCreateClientError());
            }
            $this->loggingModel->create([
                'description' => $this->logClient->logCreateClient(), 
                'method_operation' => 'store',
            ]);
            return redirect('client')->with('success-store','Client registered in system.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
```

In logic the code seems to work when all the form fields are filled in correctly, otherwise the IF I made doesn't work.

Comment: `I used dd($validations); and dd($ClientModel::create($validations));` Can you show the output to us

Comment: You do realise that `dd()` stands for Dump and Die and kills the script I assume

Comment: @RiggsFolly i will update my question.

Comment: @Riggs i updated my question with images.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 3):

When your data is invalid `$request->validated()` throws an ValidationException. And laravel handles this exception by default with an automatic redirect back to the previous action.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

> If validation fails during a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response to the previous URL will be generated. If the incoming request is an XHR request, a JSON response containing the validation error messages will be returned.

When you don't want this behaviour of an automatic redirect, you could catch the ValidationException like so:

```
try {
    $validated = $request->validated();
} catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
    // Data is invalid, do something else...
}
```

Comment: Are you say for me use ```$validated = $request->validate([ 'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255', 'body' => 'required', ]);``` and verify if ```$validated``` is true to show me the that i want?

Comment: @Lidely No, this also throws a ValidationException, when the data is invalid. I've updated my answer, how you can prevent the behaviour of an automatic redirect.

Comment: I will test your snippet code more later.